# How can I load() or get() a html page and save it in a variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, kendo-ui

How can I load() or get() a html page and save it in a variable?

I ask this question to be able to load view from separate file in kendo.View. All the kendo sample explain how to deal with layout and view from string :

```
var foo = new kendo.View("<span>Foo</span>");
```

It's not clean to use string like this. I woulk like to be able to do womething like :

```
var bar = new kendo.View(viewLoader.loadView("app/bar.html"));
```

With somethink like this

```
var viewLoader = (function ($, host) {
    //Loads external templates from path and injects in to page DOM
    return {
        //Method: loadExtTemplate
        //Params: (string) path: the relative path to a file that contains template definition(s)
        loadView: function (path) {
            //Use jQuery Ajax to fetch the template file
            var tmplLoader = $.ajax({
                url: path,
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            //tmplLoader.complete(function () {
            //    //Publish an event that indicates when a template is done loading
            //    $(host).trigger("TEMPLATE_LOADED", [path]);
            //});
        }
    };
})(jQuery, document);
```

This is not working. Why? how can I simply load an html page an keep it in a var to use jendo views?

Comment: Which bit isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax()` returns a promise object, not the result of the ajax request. You need to register a callback method to get the result of the request and then return it to the caller.

```
var viewLoader = (function ($, host) {
    //Loads external templates from path and injects in to page DOM
    return {
        //Method: loadExtTemplate
        //Params: (string) path: the relative path to a file that contains template definition(s)
        loadView: function (path) {
            var html;
            //Use jQuery Ajax to fetch the template file
            var tmplLoader = $.ajax({
                url: path,
                async: false
            }).done(function(result){
                html = result;
            });
            return html;
        }
    };
})(jQuery, document);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your sample shows me explanations about my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is send back the HTML content as response. Then you can assign the entire HTML content to a variable.

```
var html = response;
var foo = new kendo.View(html);
```